# 'Could not read path' build failed error on react-native

Tags: react-native

When I run react-native run-android, the first time I run it after doing `cd android && gradlew clean`, everything runs fine. If I stop the packager and run react-native run-android a second time, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not read path 'C:\ig3\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-fr-rCA'.
> C:\ig3\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-fr-rCA

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I can do `cd android && gradlew clean` then the build will run fine, but again the next time I run, I will get the same error. It is always the second time I run my build after doing gradlew clean, I get the same error. How can I fix this so I do not need to clean every time?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is your react-native version and android build tools version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating gradle to 3.0.1, gradle wrapper to 4.1, and build tools version to 26.0.2 I don't have this issue anymore.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how to upgrade properly both gradle and the wrapper separately? Is it enough to change the distribution URL in the gradle-wrapper.properties and running gradlew or what's the correct procedure? Thanks in advance

Comment: Update gradle version in your android/build.gradle and gradle wrapper in android/gradlew/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. Next time you build, it will download the new versions.

I actually still have the issue, but it doesn't happen on every run now.